# assign function to variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a question with this lines of code :

```
def first():
    print('Hello From First')

    def wrapper():
        print('Hi From Second')

    return wrapper


first()
# a = first()
# a()
```

Outpute:

```
Hello From First
```

when i call first() the inside Function not print
but if i uncomment that 2 lines
the output change to this :

```
Hello From First
Hello From First
Hi From Second
```

i wonder why assign function to variable and call that variable
change the outpue?

thanks

Comment: Note quite sure what you are asking. Are you wondering why `'Hi From Second'` is not printed in the first example? If so, it's because the function `wrapper()` is never called. Simply defining a function does not make it run. In the second example, `wrapper()` is returned, saved to the variable `a`, and then *called*: `a()` runs the actual code and prints.

Comment: `first` returns the function `wrapper`; you assign that function to `a` then call it.

Comment: @Mark hi. if function Wrapper() is never called then why when we assign first() to variable a and then call a(), "HI from Second" was printed?

Comment: @Alex  you returned the function wrapper as the return from the function.  then you called it.   its that simple.

Comment: when you sat a = the result.  you set a to the definition of function wrapper().   then you invoke the function.   at that point you are running wrapper (using the name a and that is printing out the message you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you just execute `first()` what causes the first print. It also return the function wrapper since this is the return value, but nothing's done with this value.

When you uncomment the last 2 lines:

1. in `a = first()` you execute `first()` again what causes the addition print of `Hello From First`, but this time `a` also contains a pointer to the wrapper function.
2. You execute `a()` what causes execution of wrapper function that prints `Hi From Second`.
   Hope it was clear.

Comment: it was clear but i have one question. you wrote : It also return the function wrapper since this is the return value, but nothing's done with this value. but if run this code : 
print(first())  
output this :
Hello From First
<function first.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000022A27842D40>
and no Hi From Second in outpute

Comment: @Alex Yes, because when you `print(first())`, 2 things happening: you print `Hello From First` as written in first(), but you also print the return value of first(), which is a pointer to wrapper, and this is the other string that you see. `Hi From Second` is not printed since you didn't execute `wrapper()`, you just printed the pointer to it.

Comment: but if i change the print  inside wrapper function,to return , still not print the Hi From Second.

Comment: `def first():
    print('Hello From First')

    def wrapper():
        return('Hi From Second')

    return wrapper


print(first())
`

Comment: That is because first() is still returning a pointer to the wrapper function, and no execution of wrapper is made. If in addition to the last change you'll also make first() return `wrapper()` instead of `wrapper`, then the function will be executed and you'll see the Hi from second.

Answer (score 1):

Because inside `first()` function you return a pointer to the `wrapper()` function, so when you do: `a=first()` the `first()` function is executed and "Hello From First" is printed.
Than the function returns the pointer to the function `wrapper()` and a contains it.
So when you do `a()` it actually executes `wrapper()`

[Read more here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assign-function-to-a-variable-in-python/)